# isomorphism of two semigroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set and denote $Y = \mathcal{P}(X)$.
We consider two semigroups $G_1 = (Y,\ \cup)$ and $G_2 = (Y,\ \cap)$.

I must prove that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic.

Comment: I think about DeMorgan law, but don't know how to use it =(

Comment: Hint: $A\mapsto C_XA$ (the last stands for the complementary set)

Comment: I don't understand what is $A↦C_XA$/ But I think I prove it by this: $f(x)=\bar x$

Comment: I understand you. It's almost the same as what you meant. Thanks=)

Comment: Actually, $G_1$ is a monoid with the empty set as neutral element, and $G_2$ is a monoid with $X$ as neutral element. These two monoids are isomorphic and since an isomorphism maps neutral element to neutral element, an isomorphism from $G_1$ to $G_2$ should map the empty set to $X$. This is a strong hint to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the map $\varphi: G_1\to G_2$ mapping $S\mapsto X\setminus S$. Then, $$\varphi(S\cup T)= X\setminus(S\cup T) = (X\setminus S)\cap(X\setminus T) = \varphi(S) \cap \varphi(T)$$
so this is a morphism of semigroups. It is an isomorphism because its inverse is itself, set-theoretically.